# Multiprocessing - asynchronous processes, but block based on function argument

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to call an external executable over and over with many different arguments. For me the executable is a black box and reads/writes to files in its directory. Therefore, I have 4 copies of the executable, each in their own directory. This allows me to run the executable 4 at a time without collision.

Originally I tried something like this

```
PROCESSES = 4
with multiprocessing.Pool(PROCESSES) as pool:
    exe_list = [ii for ii in range(4)]*10
    TASKS = ((pyfcn, (ii, ex)) for ii, ex in enumerate(exe_list))

    results = [pool.apply_async(calculate, t) for t in TASKS]

    print('Ordered results using pool.apply_async():')
    for r in results:
        print('\t', r.get())
    print()
```

which demonstrates calling a python function which then calls the external executable. `exe_list` is a list that has `[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,...]` specifying the executables. `ii` is just a stand in for the real function arguments that also get passed to the executable. Although this method returns the results in order (which I want), if for example the process using executable 2 isn't finished before 3, 0, and 1 are finished, then I get a collision when another process tries to begin using executable 2.

How can I get the results in order, use the processors asynchronously, but also prevent collisions of the external executable that is being called? Basically I want to "block" only if I've gone through the cycle of 4 executables and one isn't finished.

Maybe 7/10 executable calls finish quickly enough, but it's inevitable that I get a collision because of the fact that some of the function arguments take longer for the executable to process.

Comment: Do you have a way to tell if a given executable is finished or not?  Are you keeping track of the PID?  It seems like you might be better off not passing the executable to the function, but just having the function check each executable in turn and call the first one that is finished.  Also given this it's not clear that you need to use multiprocessing at all.  You can just have a single loop that polls the executables and runs a new one when an old one is finished.  The multi-process nature of the task is already achieved by running separate executables.

Comment: I can definitely set it up so I know if each executable is available or not. Thanks for this idea, I had been fixated on solutions using multiprocessing.

Comment: Any specific reason why the executable might collide? Does it write to a hardcoded file on disk? Does it make unprotected use of OS resources?

Comment: The executable writes to hardcoded files on disk as part of the computations it performs. It's a numerical simulation model that's a few decades old - if it were written today it would probably use RAM.